# How to apply a function using two Series as input with the output being a DataFrame of the function result of each combination of arguments?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have two Series, each containing variables that I want to use in a function. I want to apply the function for each combination of variables with the resulting output being a DataFrame of the calculated values, the index will be the index from one Series and the columns will be the index of the other Series.

I have tried searching for an answer to a similar problem - I'm sure there's one out there but I'm not sure how to describe it for search engines.

I've solved the problem by creating a function using for loops, so you can understand the logic. I want to know if there is a more efficient operation to do this without using for loops.

From what I've read, I'm imagining some combination of a list comprehension with zipped columns to calculate the values, which is then reshaped into the DataFrame but I can't solve it this way.

Here's the code to reproduce the problem and current solution.

```py
import pandas as pd

bands = pd.Series({'A': 5, 'B': 17, 'C': 9, 'D': 34}, name='band')
values = pd.Series({'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 1.02, 'Mar': 1.05, 'Apr': 1.12}, name='values')

# Here is an unused function as an example
myfunc = lambda x, y: x * (1 + 1/y)

def func1(values, bands):
    # Initialise empty DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=bands.index, 
                             columns=values.index)

    for month, month_val in values.iteritems():
        for band, band_val in bands.iteritems():
            df.at[band, month] = band_val * (1/month_val - 1)

    return df

outcome = func1(values, bands)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) for this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bands = pd.Series({'A': 5, 'B': 17, 'C': 9, 'D': 34}, name='band')
values = pd.Series({'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 1.02, 'Mar': 1.05, 'Apr': 1.12}, name='values')

outcome = pd.DataFrame(np.outer(bands, ((1 / values) - 1)),
                       index=bands.index,
                       columns=values.index)
```

[out]

```
   Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr
A  0.0 -0.098039 -0.238095 -0.535714
B  0.0 -0.333333 -0.809524 -1.821429
C  0.0 -0.176471 -0.428571 -0.964286
D  0.0 -0.666667 -1.619048 -3.642857
```

---

As a function:

```
def myFunc(ser1, ser2):
    result = pd.DataFrame(np.outer(ser1, ((1 / ser2) - 1)),
                          index=ser1.index,
                          columns=ser2.index)
    return result

myFunc(bands, values)
```